# how do I learn the foundations of programming

Tags: c#

I'm learning computer science at school (basic c#), I was very interested in this subject so I began to research on all the languages being used and just general things about coding. While reading one of the posts on this forum I saw an advice says "don't marry one language, learn the **basic foundations of programming** and then you will succeed with every language". what does "basic foundations of programming" mean, and do I need to learn specifically or it just comes with practice and learning other languages?

Comment: I didn't downvote you personally, but questions like this are off considered off topic for StackOverflow. In my opinion you'd be best to look at places like https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming as these questions are accepted there. Good luck!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I started with visual basic years ago with the help of youtube tutorials. After that I was so interested in programming, that I attended a school with software programming as a main subject. In this school we started with Java and we learnt how object orientation works. After that I learned C and later on C++. Now I am programming in C#, Javascript and so on.

In my opinion, all you have to do is to be interested in learning programming and choose the language you like. It's true that after you are familiar with one language, you are able to change to another one since most of the time only the synthax differs from the language you've learnt.

If you start with C#, please don't start with graphical apps like WPF or WinForms. Try to start with console applications and try to learn the basics like object orientation, type casting and so on. As far as I know the Microsoft Virtual Academy provides a lot of free videos to get into programming. Just check some of them out.

**Link**: https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/programming-in-c-jump-start-14254?l=j0iuozSfB_6900115888

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

"Learn the basic foundations of programming" simply means to learn concepts, not languages. Languages come and go. It's easy enough to memorize the syntax of a single language and figure out through trial and error what each piece of code is doing in that language, but when you eventually move to another language, you're stuck repeating that process of memorizing code without ever learning what's going on with the code and why it works. This would be comparable to knowing how to operate a microwave without knowing why food comes out nice and hot after 2 minutes.

Many languages share common concepts and structures. A `for` loop, for example, appears in almost every programming language out there, but each language implements a `for` loop in a different way. However, if you learn the basics of what a `for` loop is, how it operates, and what it's basic purpose is, you can apply that understanding to every language you come across.

Even more basic foundations would be learning about concepts such as memory storage, caching, sorting algorithms, and boolean operators. These are all concepts that apply to every language and will improve your ability to effectively use a language if you have a firm grasp on them.

More basic than that would be learning about the computer itself. What is a CPU? What is RAM? If you understand the hardware of a computer, again, you can apply that knowledge to every language out there.